# AWS CodeCommit read only acces

Tags: aws-codecommit

I wanted to give to a specific user read only access to some folders in a CodeCommit repository.
It is possible to do it without granting the user the permission to list all other folders in the repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, AWS CodeCommit only allows configuring resource access permissions at the Repository level, so you will unfortunately not be able to configure folder/directory level permissions at this time.

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/access-permissions.html#access-permissions-syntax